# how to see console logs on iphone?

Tags: iphone

I developed an applications on gps functionality.

I stuck up with some problem, i want to see the user location coordinates from the device.

I kept NSLogs wherever its required for me, if i connect the device to mac and if i run i

am able to see the logs in console,

But in my requirement i have to roam to some other other location and i need to get the logs.

how to get logs from device?

can we get these logs by writing them to any file?

if at all we are writing to any file, after connnecting the device to itunes how to get the file where i have writtern?

thanks in advance..... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the Organizer's console or device log can be "written" by the app and, when connect it, you can see it on the Organizer.

Another "low technology" solution is to save on disk the data (as a Plist) and show it into the app via UITable or UITextView.

Comment: is there any other way..by writing logs to files on to the iphone device memory and after that getting them by connecting the device to mac-itunes?

Comment: You can't retrieve files of the bundle of an application on iTunes, I think. So, I don't know if you can write a file on the Documents folder of the app, export it to another disk location visible and send it via email, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Phone Configuration Utility lets you easily create, maintain, encrypt, and install configuration profiles, track and install provisioning profiles and authorized applications, and capture device information including console logs.

It is available for Windows and Mac.

For Windows: http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1466

For Mac: http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1465

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this app [ConsoleLog for iPhone](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/consolelog/id415116252?mt=8)